# SP2013: Any difference in a list converted from 2010 vs a new 2013 list?

Tags: list

We have several sites what were imported as 2010 and "converted" to 2013.  In the site contents, the icons still look like the old 2010 icons.  When I create a new task list, it has the new 2013 icon.  Is there a noticeable difference between the 2010 converted list vs the new 2013 list?  Workflow issues?

I'm wondering if I should copy all the data from the old 2010 list into new 2013 lists.